# How to pass any number of headers to Feign client without knowing all the names?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I've a use case where I need to pass all headers that start with a certain prefix to the feign client. I don't know the number or exact names of these headers. There doesn't seem to be a way to to do this easily as the Feign client expects all headers to be specified using `@RequestHeader("name")`. It doesn't seem to support something like `@RequestHeader HttpHeaders`, which would be very useful.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, Feign doesn't support dynamic headers or query parameters using a Map. The Spring Cloud Feign client relies on the Spring annotations instead of Feign annotations, and the implementations of `AnnotatedParameterProcessor` have a bug such that they don't do what the documentation states they should be doing.

[RequestHeader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) doc:

> If the method parameter is Map, MultiValueMap, or HttpHeaders then the
>   map is populated with all header names and values.

[RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) doc:

> If the method parameter is Map or MultiValueMap and a parameter name
>   is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request
>   parameter names and values.

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/1361) that will fix this. Until then, I'm using an extension of `SpringMvcContract` that uses my own `AnnotatedParameterProcessor` implementations. I set the custom `SpringMvcContract` using a `Feign.Builder` as follows:

```
@Autowired
FormattingConversionService feignConversionService;

@Bean
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
    return HystrixFeign.builder()
            .contract(feignContract());
}

@Bean
public Contract feignContract() {
    return new EnhancedSpringMvcContract(feignConversionService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign), you should be able to specify a header map for dynamic headers.

> In cases where both the header field keys and values are dynamic and the range of possible keys cannot be known ahead of time and may vary between different method calls in the same api/client (e.g. custom metadata header fields such as "x-amz-meta-*" or "x-goog-meta-*"), a Map parameter can be annotated with HeaderMap to construct a query that uses the contents of the map as its header parameters.

```
 @RequestLine("POST /")
 void post(@HeaderMap Map<String, Object> headerMap);
```